# Video not playing in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, html5-video, relative-addressing

I created a project with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. In this project, videos are uploaded.
To prevent all users from accessing the videos, a folder named "File" was created outside the
wwwroot  and the videos were uploaded to the File folder.
Videos will not play when referenced from the File folder with the code below. What is the reason for this problem and what should I do to solve it?

```
<video src="../File/Videos/VideoName.mp4" controls width="640" height="300" loop/>
```

Comment: The reason is the browser doesn’t have access to such place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to Serve files outside of web root, You need to configure the Static File Middleware as follows

```
//.....other middleware...

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "File")),
    RequestPath = "/File"
});

//.....other middleware...
```

Then Use this code to show video:

```
<video src="@Url.Content("File/video/VideoDemo.mp4")" controls width="640" height="300" loop/>
```

Demo:

[image]

[image]

More details you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0)